# Wilson Theorem to find least nonnegative residue modulo m

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, reduced-residue-system

I want to know  how can we use Wilson's theorem to find least nonnegative residue modulo $m$. For example:

$$n = 64! \quad m = 67$$

Can you please explain the process step by step?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since $m = 67$ is prime, it is clear from Wilson's Theorem that: $66! \equiv 66 \pmod {67}$. Further observe that since $\gcd(66,67) = 1$, by the Cancellation Law for modular arithmetic, we have:

\begin{align}\tag1 65! \equiv 65 \cdot (64!) \equiv 1 \pmod{67}\end{align}

Knowing that $65 \equiv -2 \pmod{67}$ and $\gcd(65,67) = 1$, we can see that the linear congruence $65x \equiv -2x \equiv 1 \pmod{67}$ has a solution, namely $x = 33$. Multiplying both sides of congruence $(1)$ by $33$, we get:

\begin{align}(65 \cdot 33) \cdot 64! &\equiv 64! \pmod{67}\\
&\equiv 33 \pmod{67}\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! that helped alot

Comment: how did you get 65 is congruent to -2 mod 67 like how did you get the -2?

Comment: By definition, $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ is equivalent to $n \mid a-b$. Verify for yourself that the given numbers work with the definition. Note that we are describing the congruence class $65 \pmod{67}$.

Comment: can you explain the process step by step i am still confused i am so sorry. I  get up to 66=66 65 64! after that I got lost. Thank you and I really appreciate your help

Comment: Because we want the least positive residue of $64! \pmod{67}$, after we get congruence (1), we want to figure out a way to annihilate the $65$. We must proceed here using the multiplicative inverse; in general, this only exists when for $ax \equiv \pmod{n}$, $\gcd(a, n) = 1$, or $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Furthermore, the solution is unique modulo $n$. Upon finding this inverse, we then multiply both sides of congruence (1) by that inverse, which directly confirms that $64! \equiv 33 \pmod{67}$.